# Reading a composite key in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate a dynamic property in a framework I'm using, and I'm having some difficulty.. I have two tables joined in a many to many relationship (platforms, titles, and games) games has two primary keys, titleid and platformid

```
select * from games where CONCAT(platformid,titleid) = 110
```

110 is just an example, but the record does exist with a platform of 1 and a titleid of 10...

why wont that work?

PS: I know I can rewrite the query with a where clause (platformid = 1 AND title = 10), but for the purposes of my framework, this is not an option...

EDIT: Fixed genreid error (should have been titleid, but in my actual code this was correct... )

EDIT 2: This is a scenario:

```
select * where="platforms.id=#game.platformId# AND genres.id=#game.genreId# AND games.id<>#game.id#"
```

This is a scenario when I want to find records OTHER than the one currently selected...

Comment: Are you sure you need genreid and not titleid? I am asking because your question makes this a little blurry.

Comment: Added a correction, thanks! And a scenario below that... select * where="platforms.id=#game.platformId# AND genres.id=#game.genreId# AND games.id<>#game.id#"  -- this is a situation where I want to select something that matches a platform and genre criteria, excluding the currently selected record...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a table cannot have two `PRIMARY KEY`s. You probably mean a composite key.

Second, your query would work but would also match a `(platformid, genreid) = (11, 0)`.

You may use tuple comparison syntax (of course if your framework would let you do this):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    games
WHERE   (platformid, genreid) = (1, 10)
```

or make a more complex concatenation:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    games
WHERE   CONCAT_WS(',', platformid, genreid) = '1,10'
```

Comment: Thanks, although I think I will go back to using an id column in this table... much easier solution...